# Follow favorite answer group

Tags: feature-request

Hi I would like to know if there is option to follow like 'twitter' not precisely
but to some extent to follow your favorite answer group so that even if you miss
some questions here on Stack overflow you would be still attached to it.

Like for example I usually love hearing answers from Jon skeet ,org.life.java etc..
but sometimes missed their replies(answers).

If there is any feature to follow these users it will keep me updated what they had answered
lately.

My two cents
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

RSS? For example, [since you cite Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/22656)

Comment: i would love to see in my Login item as a tab.